# Reversing the digits of an integer

Tags: java, strings

For CS class, I had to reverse the digits of an integer from the input. This is my solution:

```
System.out.println(new StringBuilder(new Integer(new Scanner(System.in).nextInt()).toString()).reverse().toString());
```

My main question is this: is this too golfed?

Obviously I could simply add whitespace and comments, but is this level of directness practical?

Also, is there a better way to do this? Perhaps something like the following:

> ```
> final String string = new Integer(new Scanner(System.in).nextInt()).toString();
> for (int i = string.length(); i != -1; System.out.print((i-- != 0) ? string.charAt(i) : "\n"));
> ```

Comment: Well if you want all your program in one line this is excellent. If you want maintainable and readable code this is really not a good way to go!

Comment: Hi, I have downvoted your question. Please see our [help/on-topic] to see what we're all about. You could edit the question to include working code that you want peer reviewed; a golfed one-liner isn't going to get you much of a useful code review ;)

Comment: @Mat'sMug I didn't really mean to golf it; I just don't like to have (let me count) up to four middlemen variables. I am sort of asking to ungolf it.

Comment: @Marc-Andre Yeah. Can you help with that in an answer?

Comment: Just wondering. What do you need to reverse an integer?

Comment: @Piotr It's for AP Computer Science, but I know a good bit of Java, so I like to have some fun.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

In Java, and in Code Review, the preference is for creating both highly readable, and highly efficient code.

It is an almost bizarre fact, that one leads to the other.

your code has one efficiency, and that is space-on-disk.... it is neither readable, nor high-performance.

```
System.out.println(new StringBuilder(new Integer(new Scanner(System.in).nextInt()).toString()).reverse().toString());
```

- For a start, having to scroll off the page means you have to read with your mouse, not with your eyes.
- Secondly, it is very hard to evaluate what parenthesis match when they are all clumped together.

Breaking your code down (which should not be necessary), we have:

> ```
> int valinput = new Scanner(System.in).nextInt();
> String stringinput = new Integer(valinput).toString();
> String reversed = new StringBuilder(stringinput).reverse().toString();
> System.out.println(reversed);
> ```

Now, you need error handling on the Scanner, and it needs to be closed as well. Without that, you have a program that is ugly when a user types in `123.0`.

Since you have no error handling, you may as well just junk the lines with the Integer...

And, there is no reason to convert the StringBuilder to a String directly...

Without error handling, you can:

```
System.out.println(new StringBuilder().append(scanner.nextInt()).reverse());
```

That is, effectively equivalent to your code, but it has different error-condition characteristics..

Also, it is, suprisingly, quite readable, and fast.

Now, all you need is the try/catch for the scanner, and you are sorted.

Comment: Along the lines of being clear and concise, I think `String.valueOf(valInput)` is much nicer than `new Integer(valinput).toString()`.

Answer (score 8):

> @Mat'sMug I didn't really mean to golf it; I just don't like to have
>   (let me count) up to four middlemen variables. I am sort of asking to
>   ungolf it.

Well this is the root of all one-liner code. You don't want middlemen variables, but why ? Breaking the code with middlemen variables is the **first** step to have readable code. There is a tons of reasons to have middlemen variables. Debugging will be easier, changing implementation of functionality will be easier, re-factoring the code will be easier and your code will be easier to test (That is very very important).

Let's see what you have :

> ```
>   System.out.println(new StringBuilder(new Integer(new Scanner(System.in).nextInt()).toString()).reverse().toString());
> ```

Let's start by breaking this :

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
int integerToReverse = input.nextInt();
StringBuilder reverser = new StringBuilder();
reverser.append(integerToReverse);
reverser.reverse();
String reversed = reverser.toString();
System.out.println(reversed);
```

By breaking this in smaller steps, we can observe what have goes wrong. I've added middlemen variables, but you can observe but I don't need an `Integer`.

By breaking the code, you could see that you can extract the code that reverse the int. If you need to reverse multiple times, you could just call the method with the `int` to reverse and you won't need duplicated code. This will help to encapsulate everything in his own "box" and you could changed each box more easily.

What if the user doesn't input an `int` ? There is a chance that the user doesn't input an integer. Your code isn't ready for that. You should read the documentation for `Scanner.nextInt()` and come up with something that will be more solid.

*Note* :

I though that you had a bug in your code. I was reading as you were building a `StringBuilder` with an `Integer`. This would be a bug, but it turns out that I was wrong. This is one of the consequence of one liner. You can't read it right at first. Everything is so compact that you need to de-compact it in your head or in code to understand it. This lead to bug by people that won't understand your code, change it because they need to add something (functionality, logging,etc) and will break it because they didn't break it at the right place.

Comment: This might be too much for a comment, but won't middlemen variables get messy and use more memory/slow GC?

Comment: @SimonKuang your concern is valid.  Apparently they do require collection by the GC: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19268406/java-optimization-local-variable-vs-instance-variable  However, as mentioned there, premature optimization is undesirable.  *We should focus on readability first*, and optimize only when a bottleneck is detected.

Comment: In a small program like this they very very small overhead is negligible. And as joeytwiddle said, readability is a much more important factor in most cases.

Comment: With code this simple, it probably is better to duplicate. You may need to call it with different `int`s, but it's equally likely that you may need additional string processing in some of those instances, so why not leave the caller responsible for creating its own StringBuilder? You're essentially only encapsulating `append` and `reverse`.

Comment: @nmclean For a CS class, I'm no so sure that duplicating is the way to go. Yes you're essentially encapsulating `append` and `reverse` but the major is that you're also encapsulating a functionality. You're organizing your code.

Answer (score 6):

Why not throw in some arithmetics?

```
private static String reverseInt(int i) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for(int d = i; d != 0; d /=10) {
        sb.append(d % 10);
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

While using a String operation on this is probably the easiest and the fastest way to reverse an interger, you could also do it without casting

NOTE: this only works with integers, not with any decimal numbers.

```
int number = 12345;
int result = reverseInteger(number);

public int reverseInteger(int number) {
    int reverse = 0;

    while(number > 0) {
        reverse *= 10;
        reverse += number % 10;
        number /= 10;
    }

    return reverse;
}

// To get a String as result, use String.valueOf(reverse);

/*
-- start --
reverse = 0
number = 12345
-- first run --
reverse = 0 * 10 + 5 = 5
number = 1234
-- second run --
reverse = 5 * 10 + 4 = 54
number = 123
-- third run --
reverse = 54 * 10 + 3 = 543
number = 12
-- fourth run --
reverse = 543 * 10 + 2 = 5432
number = 1
-- fifth run --
reverse = 5432 * 10 + 1 = 54321
number = 0
*/
```

Comment: That way you lose zeros at the end, e.g. `reverseInteger(12300)` gives you `321`.

Comment: Darn you're right ... I forgot how I used to fix that. You could do it by checking the length and adding zeroes, but that'll take you back to String-operations or it'd add a lot more code.

Comment: For reversing an Integer, this doesn't matter. If you would want to keep the preceding zeroes, for some String operation, you won't be able to use this code

Answer (score 2):

You could also go the character array route, which is the fastest in runtime.  Here is a version that works with negative numbers:

```
public String reverseString(String str) {
    if (str == null) return null;
    char[] chars = str.toCharArray();
    int rightmost = (chars[0] == '-') ? 0 : 1;
    for (int i = (rightmost + 1) % 2; i < chars.length / 2; i++) {
        int tmp = chars[i];
        chars[i] = chars[chars.length - rightmost - i];
        chars[chars.length - rightmost - i] = tmp;
    }
    return new String(chars);
}
```

Comment: Does this work with negative numbers?

Comment: So `-1234` would become `4321-`. What happens if you parse this to a number?